# Cannot send transction or basic ouput with iota.c

Tags: hornet, client-library

I am using the latest version of iota.c client lib (v1.0.1) together with a local hornet node (v2.0.0-rc2).

When compiling iota.c and executing the example found [here](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.c/blob/v1.0.1/examples/wallet/send_basic_output.c) to send a basic output together with my hornet node running locally I get the following error:

```
Sender address: rms1qzgmsrsf94544n4zwhj3nee9s4ej4zdr5s68u4jgkc5rx5l74acu5xh8mt3
Receiver address: rms1qrtn3fjyjhdyspkdzy3nudc5l59sshdtlynl3rzwmc3mud23np6ug6sz0gh
Amount to send: 1000000

Sending transaction block to the Tangle...
[wallet_get_unspent_basic_output_ids:81] Err: Not Found, error: code=404, message=Not Found
[wallet_get_unspent_outputs_and_create_remainder:756] failed to get unspent basic output IDs
[wallet_send:928] can not collect unspent outputs or create a reminder output
Sending block to the Tangle failed!
```

When using the example to sent native tokens, a similiar error appears:

```
Creating alias address:
Sender address: rms1qzgmsrsf94544n4zwhj3nee9s4ej4zdr5s68u4jgkc5rx5l74acu5xh8mt3
State controller address: rms1qrtn3fjyjhdyspkdzy3nudc5l59sshdtlynl3rzwmc3mud23np6ug6sz0gh
Governor address: rms1qzxz3y69rg0827wc2kl6aw8psh72zuk3n596fe8rh7vsgeh2nxwkwce2z4z
Receiver 1 address: rms1qry9ufqlt4xgzfrqr5fsf4lw7ss5ggv6l9rsz99v8qm6c3qc5z4vjne829q

Sending create alias transaction block to the Tangle...
[wallet_get_unspent_basic_output_ids:81] Err: Not Found, error: code=404, message=Not Found
[wallet_get_unspent_outputs_and_create_remainder:756] failed to get unspent basic output IDs
[wallet_send:928] can not collect unspent outputs or create a reminder output
[wallet_alias_output_create:192] can not send alias output create block
Sending block to the Tangle failed!
```

My hornet node runs on the shimmer testnet which seems to work correctly.
I can send tagged data without any issues so the problem appears only in these to examples.

Do you have any ideas what the issue is?
Have I forgotten to set some configuration parameter in my hornet node?

I appreciate you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sender address has 0 balance as one can see from [here](https://explorer.shimmer.network/testnet/addr/rms1qzgmsrsf94544n4zwhj3nee9s4ej4zdr5s68u4jgkc5rx5l74acu5xh8mt3). You need to transfer funds to that address using the [faucet](https://faucet.testnet.shimmer.network/).

The code is looking for unspent outputs owned by the address but the address do not have any as one can see from [here](https://api.testnet.shimmer.network/api/indexer/v1/outputs/basic?address=rms1qzgmsrsf94544n4zwhj3nee9s4ej4zdr5s68u4jgkc5rx5l74acu5xh8mt3).

You can not spend what you do not own :).

**Edit**

Could  also be that your node do not have the inx-indexer extension installed. Because the outputs are asked to the indexer api no to the core api. So the response is Not Found. Look into [this](https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/inx-indexer/welcome/)

Comment: Hi Eddy, thank you for the quick response. However, I was already using addresses that do have a sufficient amount of SMR ( with the help of faucet) but got the same error. Are zero value transaction still supported? Because this fails too.

Comment: Try changing SLIP44_COIN_TYPE_IOTA to SLIP44_COIN_TYPE_SHIMMER in the example. I doubt this is the cause but you could try. This will produce new addresses.

Comment: Could be also that your node do not have the inx-indexer extension installed. Because the outputs are asked to the indexer api no to the rest api. So the response is Not Found. Look into [this](https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/inx-indexer/welcome/)

Comment: Yes that was it. It looks like the inx-indexer was missing. Thanks a lot!